# NS2/3 Simulation

Tags: simulation, ns2, ns-3

Over some period of time we have studied the NS software design and functionalities and have made some additions to add some more features which we think could add to the value of the software.

Anyone with experience in the field or thinks can give inputs please connect with me.

Looking for connections and feedbacks.

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad and is not a good fit for this site. You should [edit] it to be more specific. For more help, see [ask]. I'd also advise taking the [tour].

Comment: See / ask at  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users

Comment: Agree with the comments above. Nonetheless, if your contributions are significant, you can contact the maintainers using the NS-3 mailing list on Google Groups.